# Magento - Unable to Apply Catalog Price Rules

Tags: magento

We are having some issues with getting a Magento store to apply catalog price rules. It is a fairly large store (2 store fronts, 30000 products), and we are trying to apply a global discount to most of the products in the store.

We can set up the price rule, but when we go to apply it it just spins for up to an hour or so and then hangs, without applying any prices.

At a guess it's because it's trying to write so many records to the DB and it's eventually timing out, but it doesn't seem to matter what time limits we set at the server and PHP level, it never completes.

I didn't know if there was a way we could do this differently to make it more efficient?

Comment: I am having the same issue with magento 1.7.0.2 - the result is blank window. Error.log says -  PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2902458368 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes). Is it really possible that 3 gb of ram is not enough? (33000 products, 1 store view)

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 3):

Below is approach which we apply for large catalog when saving catalog price rule.

I've created one script to apply catalog rule, run with command line. And also create cron job  to run this script over night.

Just create one php file on root of your magento and placed below code in this file

```
 try {
        Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->applyAll();
        Mage::app()->removeCache('catalog_rules_dirty');
        echo Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('The rules have been applied.');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('Unable to apply rules.');
        print_r($e);
    }
```

And run with command line or create cron job for this script. This will apply your all catalog rules,

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try and get back to you - as a note to anyone else who reads this, you will need to call require "app/Mage.php"; to pull in the Mage class.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this by making sure the database user has privileges to create tables into magento database.

Applying price rules seems to create some temporary tables which my database user wasn't allowed to do.

Settings are located in `app/etc/local.xml`

Hope this saves someones day :)

-MPu